# How do I programatically unlock screen on rooted device?

Tags: android, root, lockscreen

I want to disable screen locker in (even if it is locked) or change it to some simple lock, for example swipe to unlock, in my app when notebook is near, so I will not have to write my 12-digits PIN code every time I want to read notifications.

I know how to detect notebook presence in the same network (it is not secure, but security by obscurity is enough for me), but I couldn't find anything else than it's impossible on non-rooted devices. There's an system app that takes care of setting up the lock screen, so it must be possible.

I'm running on Android 4.4.

Comment: On Android 5.0 and higher, Google SmartLock has a "when a device is nearby" option for automatic unlocking: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6093922?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
        | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
        | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
wl.acquire();

KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("name");
kl.disableKeyguard();
```

Comment: The first method just put my activity over lock screen, so I have had to enter PIN when I press back button. The second method is what I looked for. Thanks

Comment: I'll edit the answer removing the first part. Thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: Disabling the keyguard is not a solution for how to unlock